# "man" command returning duplicated results in mac terminal

Tags: macos, shell, manpage

When I

```
man -k "^printf"
```

in terminal,
it returns duplicated results below:

```
printf(1)                - formatted output
printf(1)                - formatted output
printf(3), fprintf(3), sprintf(3), snprintf(3), asprintf(3), dprintf(3), vprintf(3), vfprintf(3), vsprintf(3), vsnprintf(3), vasprintf(3), vdprintf(3) - formatted output conversion
```

And,
When I

```
man -k 1
```

It also returns a bunch of duplicated results.

It's a new M1 MAX Mac,
I didn't even do any setting changes yet, but the problem above is actually happening.
What's wrong with my new Mac?

Comment: The difference between `(1)` and `(3)`, at least, is that `printf(1)` is a command-line tool, while `printf(3)` is the family of library functions (which `printf(1)` makes use of). I'm not sure why `printf(1)` is listed twice, but I can reproduce it and consider it harmless.

Comment: @chepner how do you reproduce the twice-listed issue?

Comment: Not entirely sure :) I get the duplicate result on my M1 laptop (macOS 11.5.2), but not on my intel iMac (macOS 10.15.7).

Comment: @chepner The issue is really annoying. When I do “man -k 1”, it actually lists the whole output twice.

Comment: @chepner I tried the same thing on my wife’s M1 chip macbook 2020 model. It has no such issue though.

Answer (score 1):

There's a bug in Apple's `man(1)`, as recently as Ventura 13.4.1. If you have `groff(1)` in your path and there is no preformatted "cat" page, then the requested page will be displayed twice.

In `/usr/bin/man`, see function `man_display_page()`. If `groff(1)` is on `$PATH`, then `man_display_page_groff()` is called (which displays the page the first time), after which the script *should* return; but it erroneously falls through and displays the page a second time. The issue was flagged downstream here:

https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/133561

I've also reported the issue to Apple via feedbackassistant.apple.com (these tickets cannot be publicly shared).

Answer (score 0):

You could do `man -w` and see where the man looks for manpages.
This issue (duplication of results while using `man -k printf`) arises, if your system has copies of manpages in multiple path.

In my system there are multiple man paths. See below the output of my `man -w`.

```
/usr/local/opt/w3m/share/man/de:/usr/local/opt/w3m/share/man:/usr/local/opt/binutils/share/man:/Users/xx/opt/anaconda3/share/man:/usr/local/share/man/de:/usr/local/share/man:/usr/share/man:/Library/TeX/texbin/man:/opt/X11/share/man:/Library/Apple/usr/share/man:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/share/man:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/share/man:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/share/man
```

Out of this, below two has some of the manpages replicated. For example `printf` can be found in both path.

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/share/man/

/usr/share/man/
```

If you do `ls -l` in the `MANPATH`, you will see that both has copies of some of the same manpages.

```
 > ls /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/share/man/
man1 man2 man3 man4 man5 man6 man7 man8 man9 mann


> ls /usr/share/man/
man1 man4 man5 man6 man7 man8 man9 mann
```

*In short, when you do `man -k somecommand`, **it displays results from all the paths contained in `man -w`**. If you want to avoid that you need to change the `$MANPATH` environment variable. Set it to the path you want your man command to look.*

Comment: I don’t get what you trying to tell, Thank you for answering my question though!

Comment: Updated answer. Could you try `man -w`  and paste the output?

Comment: Can you do `man -w printf`. Then add the displayed path to `$MANPATH` and try to do the `man -k printf` again and checks whether there are any duplicates now? Let me know, if this works or not!

Comment: `man -w` out puts >>> /usr/share/man:/Library/Apple/usr/share/man:/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/share/man:/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/share/man

Comment: I guess the solution is to run `/usr/libexec/makewhatis` to reset & update the man db to the newest version. The problem is that it would occur error >>> makewhatis: /usr/share/man/whatis.tmp: Read-only file system

Comment: Yes. That is the solution. There are some discussions in this thread https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250806874 . Meanwhile you could also set the manpath environment variable (discussed above) to one of your path that has all the manpages as an alternative solution. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

As Kurt Starsinic pointed out, there is a bug in macOS `man` binary.

We could fix the problem via following steps to override system `man`:

```
brew install man-db
cd $(brew --repo)/bin
ln -s gman man
```